# Should I buy more RAM for my Lubuntu 18.04 host / Virtual Box Wins 8.1 Guest?

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-machines

I am running Lubuntu host and virtual box Wins 8.1 guest together, and looking at the current RAM on my machine the output is this:

[image: My Lubuntu Free Memory]

Even though there is a slight degradation in performance in the overall computer setup, would buying another 8GB of ram improve the performance of my machine significantly? The screenshot I've put up is just my laptop idling. I won't be playing games, and more about using MS powerpoint in the VB.

Sys info:

Thinkpad E460 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz

Comment: Buying a bit more RAM would probably improve performance as your computer is committing about 1.6 gb to its [swap file](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s1-swap-what-is.html) (which is used when your dedicated RAM is full). Typically, swap or page files are written to/from HDD which is many magnitudes of times slower than RAM, even if it is an SSD.

Comment: Keep in mind, your laptop only accepts [DDR3 (up to 1886) RAM up to 16 GB](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/e-series/e460/) despite its processor accepting [32 GB of DDR4-2133 split over two slots](https://ark.intel.com/products/88193/Intel-Core-i5-6200U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2_80-GHz).

Comment: Thanks for helping. I went to strip out my old laptops of their DDR3 ram to see if I can use one of the 4gb to get 12gb ram but my system doesn't recognize, not sure why https://i.imgur.com/UoUcXui.png any ideas?

Comment: [Could be a software imposed limit as 12 GB is not listed as an official upgrade for the laptop](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Lenovo/thinkpad-e460). Keep in mind that Hardware Recs is more focused on recommending purchasable hardware solutions. For a more in-depth technical support question, you may get better help from our affiliate site [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour).